# ShouldIi unload javascript script?

Tags: javascript, css

i want to know if it will effect the site to not unload javascript and css files, when other files are keep loading on the site. well im creating functionality like facebook with ajax, so i was wondering if i have to unload the javascript/css resource on new page call.

**Little more explanation:** ok when you go to facebook.com, it start loading the page in background with ajax. and if you click on any page/profile/section it will load the required css/javascript for it, but im not sure if they unload the required javascript, which no longer need on new request. so i was wondering, should i leave the javascript which was loaded previously or should i remove it, cause removing is not hard part, just keeping track might be little complex for a big site.

any pros/cons?

Comment: Can you post some more details as to what you are trying to do, I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "unload js and css files"?

Comment: sorry, added more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could "unload" javascript would be to unset the script objects created by the loaded script.

So if you script is:

```
var awesome = {

    init : function()
    {
        /** init stuff **/
    },

    do_stuff : function()
    {
        /** do awesome stuff **/        
    }

}
```

You could technically "unload" it by doing something like:

```
awesome = null;
```

But you'd have to be pretty tidy with your loaded script.. and there's still the potential issue with event handlers still being attached to some elements of the dom.

Comment: ya im not worried about the event handler, because html will change with the unload file.. so im assuming all the events will go with it, unless it was live event.. m i right?

Comment: @Basit. Yes probably, testing would tell. Though really the better approach would be to keep the scripts loaded and keep records of which script is loaded and only load once on demand when needed.

Comment: Using JQuery to remove the elements from the DOM will also remove the event handlers and perform any cleanup necessary. If you just implicitly remove them with something like .innerHTML you can create leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should put logic in place that determines whether you need to load the script in the first place.  If it's not necessary for the particular page/view, then don't load it.

The only way to "unload" that I can think of is to reload the page without it, which seems like a terrible idea IMHO.